# Inverse of a function - $f^-(x)$ in a restricted domain

Tags: functions

I have a function $f(x) = y = x^2(3-2x)$, $0\le x\le 1$, I would like to find the inverse of this function on this restricted domain. ,This seems to be the answer for one of the problems that I have been scratching my head for a day.

I used online calculators, but the problem is I cannot evaluate the inverse in this domain as part of the function is $\sqrt{(y-1)y}$ and y ranges in $0<y<1$.  Could someone suggest an inverse of this function restricted to (0,1). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Mathematica, the solution for $x$ in terms of $y$ is
$$x=\frac{1}{4} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{y^2-y}+2
   y-1}+\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{4 \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{y^2-y}+2
   y-1}}+\frac{1}{2}.$$
Perhaps, more complicated than you expected, particularly since it involves the imaginary unit $i$. However, it is a fundamental fact that cubic equations often require complex numbers to solve completely - *even* when the solutions are known to be real.  This is known as the Casus Irreducibilis and is fully described on [its Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis). That same page indicates how the equation can be solved by hand.

As far as checking whether this is really the "inverse", you can always look at a plot, as inverse functions have graphs that are mirror images of one another about the line $y=x$.  I entered the following into WolframAlpha:

```
plot (3y^2-2y^3, 1/2+(1-I*Sqrt[3])/(4*(-1+2*y+2*Sqrt[-y+y^2])^(1/3))+((1+I*Sqrt[3])*(-1+2*y+2*Sqrt[-y+y^2])^(1/3))/4), y=0..1
```

to get [this](http://goo.gl/KOu9i3):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should solved $x$ in this equation $$3x^2-2x^3=y.$$

Secondly, you would be to determine the Domain of $f^{-1}$, i.e. the range of $f(x), x\in [0,1]$.

Since $f'(x)=(3x^2-2x^3)'=6x(1-x)\le 0$, $f(1) \ge f(x) \ge f(0), i.e., 1\ge f(x) \ge 0$.

So the domain of $f^{-1}$ is $[0,1]$

Comment: The problem as I had stated in the problem the range for the inverse is (0,1) and when I solve the cubic equation in terms of y, you get sqrt of a negative number and becomes complex as the inverse is found on a wider range of x.  Is there a special function that would give x in terms of y where I don't stumble upon the problem that I discussed above.

Comment: @satishramanathan: it is difficult to give $x$ in terms of $y$